# Maven Properties Plugin - doesn't work in inheritance

Tags: maven-plugin

I have this directory structure

```
root
 |- pom.xml
 |- submodule1
      |- pom.xml
      |- project.properties
      |- subsubmodules
           |-pom.xml
```

Submodule1 inherits from root and subsubmodules inherit from submodule1

Subsubmodules has dependencies that uses properties from submodule1's project.properties to have define its version.
ie in Subsubmodules

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>some.org</groupId>
<artifactId>someartifact</artifactId>
<version>${themodules.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In project.properties of Submodule1, I have

```
themodules.version = 1.0
```

So I used the properties-maven-plugin by defining it in the root pom.xml

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
              <!-- *edited from earlier post <file>etc/config/dev.properties</file>-->
<file>${basedir}/project.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then I run mvn install at root level. Maven says it can't resolve ${themodules.version} in dependencies.

I also ran mvn install at the submodule level and it still can't resolve.

Help pls

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with code another developer checked in.
They had the *properties-maven-plugin* under the root *pom.xml*.

I moved it out to each subproject that consumed the properties, and made it path relative.
Since the main pom is in *${project.basedir}*, the subproject will be in *../${project.basedir}*.

That is, I added the *plugin* to the *plugins* element in those poms, and set the file element to *${project.basedir}/../default-pom.properties*.

When I did that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with inheritance here, you just need add location of your project.properties to properties-maven-plugin's configuration in your root pom.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <files>
    <file>etc/config/dev.properties</file>
    <file>${project.basedir}/submodule1/project.properties</file>
  </files>
</configuration>
```

Then do mvn clean install at root level.

Comment: Sorry, I added the <file> as <file>${basedir}/project.properties</file> in root pom.xml and assumed that it will be inherited to submodule pom model. Thus it should read the project.properties in submodule. Is this assumption incorrect? Given that inheritance works bottom-up approach its quite hard for the parent to know exactly who their children are and where exactly will the project.properties file be within the children

Comment: @ALQH, there is no concept for properties file inheritance, you just need tell properties-maven-plugin where is the exact location to read the properties file.

Comment: I declared that in root pom.xml, but then it still can't pass the ${themodules.version} that was used as dependency version in subsubmodules when I ran mvn install. It says dependency.dependency.version is not valid.

Comment: @ALQH, did you run mvn install under root? if you run mvn install under root/submodule1, it will not work as ${project.basedir} is now point to root/submodule1, if you want to run mvn install from outside root, change ${project.basedir} to a fix absolute file path.

Comment: I ran mvn install from root. Maven will then do install for the submodules from that and when maven gets to submodule1's pom.xml it can't resolve the properties.

Comment: Essentially what I intended is that submodule1 will inherit the root's configuration for reading .properties file then read the project.properties file within submodule1 and pass the properties read by submodule1 to subsubmodules.

Comment: This has everything to do with inheritance. Normal project properties get inherited, but not the ones read by properties-maven-plugin. Rereading properties in each project is a workaround of that problem. Sure it's fast, but if you have a 100 projects this adds up to a minute... https://github.com/mojohaus/properties-maven-plugin/issues/32